# SQL Server : use logic (if statement ) in table join criteria

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, join, conditional-statements

I want conditional table join criteria based on the value of a filed in each table row.

Something like:

```
select * 
from t1 
join t2 on t1.product = t2.product
        and (
             IF (t1.export = 1)
             Begin
                t2.export in (0,1)
             Else Begin
               t2.export= 0
             END)
```

So depending on the value of a table row, join it accordingly.

Thanks as always,

Comment: Did you tried with a `Case` statement.?

Comment: Are 0 and 1 the only possible values for t1.export?

Comment: Hi Anand, yes tried `case when T1.export= 1 then t2.export in (0,1)
  else   t2.export= 0
  END 
  ` but SQL does not know what to do near the first 'in'[in(0,1)].

Comment: yes, 0 and 1 only possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `t1.export` can take on `NULL` values, then the equivalent logic is:

```
on t1.product = t2.product and
   ((t1.export = 1 and t2.export in (0, 1)) or
    (t1.export <> 1 and t2.export = 0) or
    (t1.export is null and t2.export = 0)
   )
```

or, alternatively:

```
on t1.product = t2.product and
   (t2.export = 0 or
    t1.export = 1 and t2.export = 1
   )
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1 JOIN t2
    ON t1.product = t2.product
    AND (
        (t1.export = 1 AND t2.export IN (0, 1))
        OR (t1.export != 1 AND t2.export = 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Since only possible values for t1.export are 0 and 1, you can just use an `IN`;

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 
  ON t1.product=t2.product 
 AND t2.export IN (0, t1.export)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to write this condition and be sure that **only the wanted condition gets evaluated in the specified order** is with a `CASE` statement, because you cannot be sure of the order of execution of the conditions and you cannot count on short-circuit in SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.product=t2.product
AND CASE t1.export
        WHEN 1 THEN CASE
                        WHEN t2.export IN (0,
                                           1) THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END
        ELSE CASE
                 WHEN t2.export = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END
    END = 1
```

You could also write it as below, but in that case conditions might be re-ordered. It will not have any impact on the result, but with more complex conditionnals it could have performance impacts.

```
AND (
    (t1.export = 1 AND t2.export IN (0, 1))
    OR (t1.export != 1 AND t2.export = 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional statement:

```
select *
from   t1
join   t2
on     t1.product=t2.product
and    ( ( t1.export = 1 and t2.export in (0,1) )
         or
         ( t1.export != 1 and t2.export = 0 )
       )
```

Comment: @Smudger What I dislike about this is that in theory, the `IN` condition could get evaluated even if `t1.export != 1` since the order of execution is entirely chosen by the optimizer.

Comment: @plalx: good point. Thanks for mentioning. Your case statement indeed fixes that. +1.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If only SQL would have more faith into the developers ;) It would have been nice to be able to do someting like `WHERE ... WITH NO_OPTIMIZATIONS` . Some conditions could be greatly simplified... `CASE` statements are so verbose.

Comment: Lol. I guess the opposite it true more often... See all those silly questions on SO ;)